# how to track changes before commiting in git

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to view the diff's of my current working state with the last previous commit, so I can compare the difference first before doing a commit. I want to see it in a very easy visual state. Just like seeing a commit in github, where you basically just see all the differences. Any idea on how to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do one of the following. Before doing `git add`:

```
git diff
```

or after `git add`:

```
git diff --cached
```

Comment: is there a better way to visually represent this, like seeing the diff's with colors.. git diff doesn't have color highlighting

Comment: Sure it does. Try `git diff --color`

Comment: Or, you can set up your [`git difftool`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-difftool.html) to use whatever difference display program you like.

Comment: yea.. I had tried doing git difftool and it uses filemerge but it sucks, any other recommendation? I won't mind paying a bit to get a better diffing software, specifically in OSX and git

Comment: I've used meld, kdiff3, and p4diff before. I don't usually use gui diff tools myself, so I can't really give a specific recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git diff HEAD` to see the changes of both staged and unstaged changes in tracked files.